# BufferedReader on top of BufferedInputStream VS BufferedReader on top of FileInputStream

Tags: java, performance, file, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

Is there any performance gain if we have:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("SOME_FILE")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

Notice that I added `BufferedInputStream`, which is unusual, to my experience.

Usually, it goes with out the added intermediate buffered input stream:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(""), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

If there's a performance difference or not, how can I measure it?

What I tried is reading ~30 MB text file using both approaches, 3 times each.

To my surprise, without the buffered input stream was around 10% faster than its buffered correspondent.

I don't know if there are cases where the buffered version shine over the other or it's just a redundant buffering causing more overhead than it's useful.

Comment: You already have a buffer with the `BufferedReader`. Adding a second buffer is unlikely to change much, a 10% penalty for buffering your buffer sounds reasonable.

Comment: You don't need to double buffer. But you can increase the performance by choosing the buffer capacity. Default value is `8192`. Depending on your system and the file you read, a higher value might be better.

Comment: Thanks @Sascha. I tried manipulating the buffer but there was no considerable performance gain. In fact, sometimes performance was worse. I tired to make the inputstream buffer much higher than the bufferedreader, then tried the reverse. So, it seems, generally a bufferedreader on top of a normal fileinputstream without buffering on the bytes level is good enough.

Comment: Might be worth checking if nio gives you any improvement: `try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of("x.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {...}`